# Não estou conseguindo fazer o valor de uma propriedade ser selecionada utilizando o Razor Helper DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

Caros, em minha aplicação ASP.NET MVC 5 que estou utilizando o .Net 4.5 não estou conseguindo fazer a opção ser selecionada para uma determinada propriedade.

Exemplo de minha classe:

```
public class Funcionario
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é necessário")]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} aceita somente entre {2} e {1}")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é necessário")]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("F")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é necessário")]
    public string Sexo { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Cargo")]
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public int? CargoId { get; set; }
}
```

O trecho de código da minha view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Nome, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Nome, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Nome", autofocus = "autofocus" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Nome)
    </div>

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Ativo, new { @class = "col-sm-1 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Ativo, ViewBag.Ativo as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Ativo)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Sexo, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Sexo, ViewBag.Sexo as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Sexo)
    </div>

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CargoId, new { @class = "col-sm-1 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CargoId, ViewBag.Cargos as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CargoId)
    </div>
</div>
```

Como retorno a view pelo Controller e como seto os valores na ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Alterar(int id)
{
    var obj = repository.Funcionarios.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.EmpresaId == SessionEmpresaId && x.Id == id)
    if (obj == null)
        return HttpNotFound();
    SetarValoresDeCadastroNaViewBag();
    return View("Cadastro", obj);
}
...
private void SetarValoresDeCadastroNaViewBag()
{
    var AtivoList = new List<dynamic>();
    AtivoList.Add(new { Id = "", Text = "" });
    AtivoList.Add(new { Id = true.ToString(), Text = "SIM" });
    AtivoList.Add(new { Id = false.ToString(), Text = "NÃO" });
    ViewBag.Ativo = new SelectList(AtivoList, "Id", "Text");

    var SexoList = new List<dynamic>();
    SexoList.Add(new { Id = "", Text = "" });
    SexoList.Add(new { Id = "M", Text = "Masculino" });
    SexoList.Add(new { Id = "F", Text = "Feminino" });
    ViewBag.Sexo = new SelectList(SexoList, "Id", "Text");

    var cargos = repository.Cargos.Where(x => x.EmpresaId == SessopmEmpresaId).Select(x => new
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Descricao = x.Descricao
    }).ToList<dynamic>();
    cargos.Insert(0, new { Id = "", Descricao = "" });
    ViewBag.Cargos = new SelectList(cargos, "Id", "Descricao");
}
```

Por fim, veja que o cargo é carregado, mas o sexo e o ativo não:

[image: Exemplo da página renderizada]

Debugando eu vi que os campos vão preenchidos para a view.
Vi também que as tags são geradas corretamente no html da página.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="Nome">Nome</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control input-sm" id="Nome" name="Nome" placeholder="Nome" type="text" value="Fulano de Tal">
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="Ativo">Ativo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control input-sm" id="Ativo" name="Ativo">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="True">SIM</option>
            <option value="False">NÃO</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="Sexo">Sexo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control input-sm" id="Sexo" name="Sexo">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="M">Masculino</option>
            <option value="F">Feminino</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="CargoId">Cargo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select class="form-control input-sm" id="CargoId" name="CargoId">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">...</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="11">Assistente Social</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Então, por favor, como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Verifique no debug se o seu `obj` no action `Alterar` contém o valor esperado, ex. `obj.Sexo = "M"`;

Comment: Sim, havia verificado e está.

Comment: Sugiro outro teste pra tentar debugar o problema, incluir na view em alguma área visível algo pra listar o conteúdo do campo: `@Model.Sexo`

Comment: Testei, os valores são impressos corretamente. Por algum motivo ao remover a adição do registro em branco, `//SexoList.Add(new { Id = "", Text = "" });`, o valor passa a ser selecionado.

Comment: Por se tratarem de dois campos requeridos eu vou remover essa linha que adiciona o registro em branco. Mas sabe o porque disso e como poderia ser feito para manter o <option> em branco sem gambiarras?

Comment: Veja a resposta que postei, assim deve funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei explicar a razão disso acontecer (algum um bug no MVC) mas o nome do campo no `ViewBag` está conflitando com o seu `Model`

Esse trecho por exemplo:

```
ViewBag.Sexo = new SelectList(SexoList, "Id", "Text");
```

Altere o nome do campo do ViewBag para `ViewBag.SexoList`, ou qualquer valor que não conflite com o `Model.Sexo`

```
ViewBag.SexoList = new SelectList(SexoList, "Id", "Text");
```

E aqui:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Sexo, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-sm-2">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Sexo, ViewBag.SexoList as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Sexo)
</div>
```